# Silverlight line of business applications

Tags: .net, silverlight

Ok I have been looking for some good examples of Line of business apps implemented in silverlight. I have come across a few bits on the net but nothing with any substance to it.

The MS silverlight samples are cool for eye candy and stuff kind of like you see done in Flash but nothing that is true LOB lets actually make something useful for companies.

Has anyone got some suggestions, links etc to start off with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MS Health CUI project contains some Silverlight LOB controls.  Check out [the codeplex source](http://mscui.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=25602) or [the main project](http://www.mscui.net/ControlsAndSamples.aspx) site for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Telerik Example Dashboard

- Link - http://www.telerik.com/products/salesdashboard.aspx
- Download Source - http://www.telerik.com/account/free-trials/single-trial.aspx?pmvid=2009

> The Telerik Sales Dashboard is a demo
>   application for monitoring a company’s
>   sales representatives’ performance.
>   The dashboard provides senior
>   management with rich data
>   visualizations for analyzing
>   enterprise data, thus facilitating the
>   decision-making process in a typical
>   business environment. The demo
>   demonstrates a best practice approach
>   for structuring a large-scale
>   enterprise application that has a
>   single business-logic layer shared by
>   two different presentation layers: a
>   desktop version (built on WPF), and a
>   web version (built on Silverlight).
>   Both UI implementations have an
>   identical look, thanks to the
>   industry’s only truly cross-platform
>   UI components –RadControls for
>   Silverlight and RadControls for WPF.
>   The two suites share the same API and
>   are derived from the same codebase,
>   enabling extensive code reuse between
>   WPF and Silverlight applications.

Answer (score 0):

I built a WCF service against Northwind with a asp.net front end.

www.telerik.com/support/kb/orm/general/northwind-wcf-demo.aspx

You can see the ajax UI at:

demo.n-sv.com/NWUI/

I'm slowly starting to work on a SL version of the UI.

demo.n-sv.com/NWSL/
Note I've only put time into the Orders portion.

With the Telerik Silverlight 3 controls, I feel you can legitimately write some SL LOB apps now.

http://www.telerik.com/products/silverlight.aspx